# Swapping side from an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have thousand of data in X and Y. I am trying to plot an interpolation graph but to start plotting it need to began from negative value.

```
x = [15000,14000,13000,12000,11000,0,-1000,-10000,-15000]
y = [1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1]
```

How can i make it into this format

```
x = [-15000,-10000,-1000,0,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000]
y = [-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = x[::-1]
y = y[::-1]
```

I'd call this "reversing" a list, not "swapping" it, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really need to *sort* the `x` list, and also move around the `y` values in the same way the `x` values were permuted, take a look at this:

```
>>> x = [15000,14000,13000,12000,11000,0,-1000,-10000,-15000]
>>> y = [1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1]
>>> x1, y1 = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y)))
>>> x1
(-15000, -10000, -1000, 0, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000)
>>> y1
(-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

So `x1` and `y1` are in the orders you want.  But they're tuples instead of lists.  If you need lists instead, then, e.g.,

```
x1, y1 = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(x, y))))
```

is one way to do it.

Bwt if all you really need is to simply reverse the lists, then @OscarLopez's answer is much easier :-)